# Why my bot doesn't wanna be online on discord?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

I'm working on a discord bot with JavaScript.
The problem is that this code doesn't return any errors, actually the terminal says that my bot is online but when I go to discord I see that it is offline!
Whats the problem?

```js
const Discord = require(`discord.js`);
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.login = `myTOKENhere`;
const prefix = `&help`;
client.on(`ready`,() => {console.log(`Bot is online`);
});

client.on(`message`, (message) => {
  console.log(message);
});
client.on(`message`, (message) => {
  if (message.content == 'ping') {
    message.reply == 'pong';
  }
});
```

Comment: You reassigned client.login from a function to your token. And you never call the (now non-callable) login function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

client.login is a function, you must use:

```js
client.login('token')
```

and place it in the end of your code.